# Where to add "junit testResults: 'results.xml', skipPublishingChecks: true" in the Jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, junit, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, tosca

I am trying to add "junit testResults: 'results.xml', skipPublishingChecks: true" in the Jenkins file but its still not working. I am getting the following error and not sure where the issue is

Error - [Checks API] No suitable checks publisher found.

```
stages{
        stage('Run Stage 1') {
            steps {
                junit testResults: 'results.xml', skipPublishingChecks: true
                tricentisCI newTricentisClientPath: 'D:\\Program Files (x86)\\TRICENTIS\\Tosca Testsuite\\ToscaCommander\\ToscaCI\\Client\\ToscaCIClient.exe', configurationFilePath: '\\\\Server\\Folder1\\Test Event XML\\Stage1.xml', newEndpoint: 'https://server/DistributionServerService/ManagerService.svc'
            }   
        }
        stage('Run Stage 2') {
            steps {
                junit testResults: 'results.xml', skipPublishingChecks: true
                tricentisCI newTricentisClientPath: 'D:\\Program Files (x86)\\TRICENTIS\\Tosca Testsuite\\ToscaCommander\\ToscaCI\\Client\\ToscaCIClient.exe', configurationFilePath: '\\\\Server\\Folder1\\Test Event XML\\Stage2.xml', newEndpoint: 'https://server/DistributionServerService/ManagerService.svc'
            }   
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you create results.xml previously? It has to exist in your Jenkins workspace.

Comment: Yes Michael . I see it under Workspace. I get this error and the subsequent stages in the Jenkins pipeline are getting skipped -                                 
"Publishing JUnit results   
Recording test results    
[Checks API] No suitable checks publisher found."